# How to render the payment fields of Adyen in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adyen

I'm trying to use Adyen payment service with my (create) React application but not able to generate the input fields because it can't find the rootNode.

**What I have tried:** 
From Adyen I have to load their checkout script inside my project. So I have created a `<script>` tag dynamical (`document.createElement('script')`) and in the body below loaded  (`document.body.appendChild(script)`). This works.

Next I have to call a method from Adyen which takes an object as an argument that will eventually populate a `div`.

**Problem:** 
This `<div className="cards-div">` I've added into my React component but I get this error: 
`index.js:1446 ERROR: SecuredFields cannot find a valid rootNode element`

It can't seem to see the created `div`. Does anybody know how I can populate these (credit card) fields or know what the best way of working with React and Adyen is?

***Update*:**

**Solution**:
I found a solution which worked for me, hopefully works also for you.
Before I was calling the Adyen service on initial render of the component. Because it takes a bit, I've created a separated function which needs to be called whichs triggers the service

Answer (score 1):

That usually happens because the adyen js is running before the dom element has been created. Make sure to call `.csf()` after the `#cards-div` element is in the dom?

Comment: I'm not using the SDK but the API integration which doesn't have the `.mount()`. Now I have solved it by triggering the `.csf()` on a later point when the `<div className="cards-div">` is created and exists

Comment: Ah, `.csf()` is what I should have said. Updated.